# Which port should I use for SQL Server on Docker with runner in bitbucket?

Tags: sql-server, docker, odbc

I'm using a python-mssql image to restore a `.bak` file on Bitbucket. This is the yaml file that I create:

```
image: diegonachon/mssql_python_sqlcmd
env:
- ACCEPT_EULA = Y
- SA_PASSWORD = 5tr0ngP455
pipelines:
custom:
run:
- step:
name: restauration
runs-on:
- 'self.hosted'
size: 8x
script:
- pip install pysftp
- pip install pyodbc
- pip install psycopg2
- mkdir /bak_db/
- python dowload_bak_file.py
- python restore_file.py
```

In `download_bak_file.py` I download a `.bak` file that I'll restore. Then, in `restore_db.py`, I restore it with this code:

```
import os
os.system(''' sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q'''
''' "Restore DATABASE data_base FROM DISK = '/bak_db/data_base.bak' \
WITH MOVE 'data_base' TO '/bak_db/data_base.mdf', \
MOVE 'data_base' TO '/bak_db/data_base.ldf' " \
-P 5tr0ngP455 ''')
```

But I get these errors:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

What I've seen, is a port problem, so I assume that I should change "localhost" with something else. Is it or I'm missing something?

Comment: I think you're missing something... The SQL Server service isn't instantly listening when the container starts, it takes time to start up - configuring itself; verifying the integrity and file format versions of existing system and user database files; etc. - before it opens a port to accept incoming connections. I know this link is for a Node app, but the concept is the same, demonstrating waiting for the SQL Server socket to be ready and listening before applying its database changes: [twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app).

Answer (score 0):

Never use localhost in docker configs. In dockers, localhost is inside the docker container itself. If you want to connect to a database, you should use its service name or machine IP.